# Call mysqli functions from another php file

Tags: php, mysqli, include

I am importing transaction data and saving it into a database.  Some of the transaction data has missing fields, so I am manually updating them using the following function from a separate file (file2.php):

```
function categoryRules() {
    //rules for transactions
    $sql = "UPDATE Transactions 
                SET cat1 = 'Shops', cat2 = 'Supermarkets and Groceries'
            WHERE name LIKE '%shipt%'";
    if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
        echo "SHIPT UPDATE PERFORMED";
    } else {
        echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
    }   
    $sql = "UPDATE Transactions 
                SET cat1 = 'Shops', cat2 = 'Food and Beverage Store', cat3 = 'Beer, Wine and Spirits'
            WHERE name LIKE '%liquor%'";
    if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
        echo "LIQUOR UPDATE PERFORMED";
    } else {
        echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
    }
    $sql = "UPDATE Transactions 
                SET cat1 = 'Service', cat2 = 'Telecommunication Services'
            WHERE name LIKE '%vzwrls%'";
    if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
        echo "VERIZON UPDATE PERFORMED";
    } else {
        echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
    }

    $sql = "UPDATE Transactions 
                SET cat1 = 'Recreation', cat2 = 'Gyms and Fitness Centers'
            WHERE name LIKE '%classpass%'";
    if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
        echo "VERIZON UPDATE PERFORMED";
    } else {
        echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
    }
}
```

To clean up my code a bit in file1.php, i am calling the file2 function on file 1.php using:

```
$conn = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $pass, $database);
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
include 'categoryRules.php';
categoryRules();
mysqli_close($conn);
```

I am getting the following response when doing so:

> **Error**: UPDATE Transactions SET cat1 = 'Shops', cat2 = 'Supermarkets
>   and Groceries' WHERE name LIKE '%shipt%'
>
> Error: UPDATE Transactions SET cat1 = 'Shops', cat2 = 'Supermarkets and Groceries' WHERE name LIKE '%shipt%'
>
> Error: UPDATE Transactions SET cat1 = 'Shops', cat2 = 'Food and Beverage Store', cat3 = 'Beer, Wine and Spirits' WHERE name LIKE '%liquor%'
>
> Error: UPDATE Transactions SET cat1 = 'Service', cat2 = 'Telecommunication Services' WHERE name LIKE '%vzwrls%'
>
> Error: UPDATE Transactions SET cat1 = 'Recreation', cat2 = 'Gyms and Fitness Centers' WHERE name LIKE '%classpass%'

It seems like the functions may be running in file 2.php before they get to file1.php, which is where I open, access, and close the database link.  Is there a way to import them into file 1?  Is there a better way to clean up this portion of the code for file 1.php besides creating file 2.php?

Comment: You had better show us what is in `'categoryRules.php';` as that seems to be where the issue is

Comment: I don't get your file structure. Why file 1 and file 2 and not using classes?

Comment: That error looks like it is coming from this line `echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);`

Comment: Error: UPDATE Transactions SET cat1 = 'Shops', cat2 = 'Supermarkets and Groceries' WHERE name LIKE '%shipt%'
Error: UPDATE Transactions SET cat1 = 'Shops', cat2 = 'Food and Beverage Store', cat3 = 'Beer, Wine and Spirits' WHERE name LIKE '%liquor%'
Error: UPDATE Transactions SET cat1 = 'Service', cat2 = 'Telecommunication Services' WHERE name LIKE '%vzwrls%'
Error: UPDATE Transactions SET cat1 = 'Recreation', cat2 = 'Gyms and Fitness Centers' WHERE name LIKE '%classpass%'

Since it doesn't have a mysqli_error output, I assume it is running in file2.php where no connection exists?

Comment: Post extra info in the question using the edit, I have done this for you this time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ahh of course, I should have thought of this earlier

You make a connection outside the function so `$conn` is not visible inside the function, just pass `$conn` to the funtion as a parameter and it will all magically work. Its a simple scope issue!

categoryRules.php

```
function categoryRules($conn) {    // <-- add parameter
    //rules for transactions
    $sql = "UPDATE Transactions 
                SET cat1 = 'Shops', cat2 = 'Supermarkets and Groceries'
            WHERE name LIKE '%shipt%'";
    if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
        echo "SHIPT UPDATE PERFORMED";
    } else {
        echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
    }   
    $sql = "UPDATE Transactions 
                SET cat1 = 'Shops', cat2 = 'Food and Beverage Store', cat3 = 'Beer, Wine and Spirits'
            WHERE name LIKE '%liquor%'";
    if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
        echo "LIQUOR UPDATE PERFORMED";
    } else {
        echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
    }
    $sql = "UPDATE Transactions 
                SET cat1 = 'Service', cat2 = 'Telecommunication Services'
            WHERE name LIKE '%vzwrls%'";
    if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
        echo "VERIZON UPDATE PERFORMED";
    } else {
        echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
    }

    $sql = "UPDATE Transactions 
                SET cat1 = 'Recreation', cat2 = 'Gyms and Fitness Centers'
            WHERE name LIKE '%classpass%'";
    if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
        echo "VERIZON UPDATE PERFORMED";
    } else {
        echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
    }
}
```

Now the main script should be

```
$conn = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $pass, $database);
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
include 'categoryRules.php';
// add $conn parameter to the call
categoryRules($conn);           
mysqli_close($conn);
```